# swapping selected values from one column to other using any transformation

Tags: kettle

I have two columns named `amount` and `work` with data in the format of given below:

```
amount   58220  84151 65999    23    78544    52656       
work        15     14    20    85597    22       19
```

and I want to swap the values of 23 and 85597 which are in the same row. Can you suggest me a suitable solution?

Answer (score 1):

Create a transformation following the steps:

1. build file `inputdata.txt` (or other source of data for the flow)

   ```
   value1, value2
   58220,  15
   84151,  14
   65999,  20
   23,     85597
   78544,  22
   52656,  19
   ```
2. add code in javascript step

   ```
   var t1 = value1;
   var t2 = value2;
   ```
3. In the menu "Fields" choose Rename `t1` to `value2` and `t2` to `value1` and check the option to replace values??.
4. the results are:

   ```
   value1, value2
   15,     58220          
   14,     84151          
   20,     65999          
   85597,  23             
   22,     78544          
   19,     52656
   ```

If you need the source code I send by email.